# How to show data from joined table if join id does not exist in joined table?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables with corresponding data:

```
RequestsTable
ReqID | ReqBy | ReqDate
1 | User1 | 30/04/2013
2 | User2 | 30/04/2013
3 | MasterUser | 30/04/2013
```

and

```
RequestorsTable
ReqUserName | ReqFullName
User1 | Sample User 1
User2 | Sample User 2
```

and i need the output to be like this:

```
ReqID | ReqBy | ReqDate
1 | Sample User 1 | 30/04/2013
2 | Sample User 2 | 30/04/2013
3 | MasterUser | 30/04/2013
```

May I know how can I do this^^?

Just a quick note: MasterUser is a superuser account and is therefore not in the database, but could make requests.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ISNULL` and a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` allows you to selectively choose what column to return in the resultset.

- If a matching record is found in RequestorsTable, use that value
- otherwise, use the ReqBy value from RequestsTable

**Sample Select statement**

```
SELECT rt.ReqID, ISNULL(rst.ReqFullName, rt.ReqBy), rt.ReqDate
FROM   RequestsTable rt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RequestorsTable rst ON rst.ReqUserName = rt.ReqBy
```

An alternative to `ISNULL` would be `COALESCE` wich [more or les](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx)s performs similar functionality.

**Sample Select statement**

```
SELECT rt.ReqID, COALESCE(rst.ReqFullName, rt.ReqBy), rt.ReqDate
FROM   RequestsTable rt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RequestorsTable rst ON rst.ReqUserName = rt.ReqBy
```

Comment: @JW - Why delete your answer? It's equivalent and posted before mine with an additional link OP could benefit from. *(and why the downvote on it?)*

Comment: No problem. *(2 more to go <g>)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      rt.ReqID
    , ReqBy = ISNULL(rt2.ReqFullName, rt.ReqBy)
    , rt.ReqDate  
FROM dbo.RequestsTable rt
LEFT JOIN dbo.RequestorsTable rt2 ON rt.ReqBy = rt2.ReqUserName
```